# How to use a custom Angular controller with $templateCache resources

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am working on a test for a piece of a controller that changes dom like this...

```
<html ng-app="blah">
  ...
  <body ng-controller="app">
     <div id="results"> Results </div>
  </body>
</html>
...
function AppController($rootScope, ..){
  $rootScope.$on('listChanged', function(data){
     $('#results').css('color',data);
  })
}
...
beforeEach(function(){
   controller = createController();
});
function createController() {
    return $controller(AppController, {
        $scope:$scope
    });
}
```

How would I test something like...

```
it("Test that text is red", function(){
    ... //Setup rootScope event
    expect($('#results').css('color')).toBe('red');
});
```

Of course that doesn't seem to work for me and I think I have to compile the html (it is already in my $templateCache) but I am not sure how to attach my controller to it once compiled. Is just passing the scope enough?

Answer (score 0):

You should use directives for DOM manipulation. Do not do DOM manipulation in controllers.

Luckily for you there is a built-in directive for this: `ng-style`

The No.1 reason DOM manipulation should not happen in controllers is test-ability. Your code is un-testable because of the jQuery code.

Here is your code refactored and testable.

```js
angular.module('blah', [])
  .controller('AppController', AppController);

AppController.$inject = ['$rootScope'];
function AppController($rootScope) {
  
  this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
  this.resultStyle = {color: 'black'};      

  var _this = this;
  $rootScope.$on('listChanged', function(event, data) {
      _this.resultStyle.color = data;
  });

}
AppController.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  // something somewhere in your code triggers this event
  
  this.$rootScope.$broadcast('listChanged', 'red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="blah">
  <div ng-controller="AppController as vm">
    <div ng-style="vm.resultStyle">Results</div>
    <button ng-click="vm.doSomething()">Do Something</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

We have removed the explicit code from the controller that turns the result red. Instead we now have a declarative property. So now we just test to see if the `resultStyle`property is set to `color = red`.

```
it('should set the result property if something happens', function() {

    // act
    controller.doSometing()

    // assert
    expect(controller.resultStyle.color).toEqual('red');

});
```

When you find you have code that breaks the patterns that makes it testable, refactor.

Comment: I get that but there are times that doesn't work and you need jQuery in the controller without toatally refactoring

Comment: @Jackie I have updated my answer to show that infact jQuery is not needed in the controller. The problem is the jQuery is what makes the code untestable. The refactor is insignificant compared to the benefits in cleanness, stability and testability.

Comment: Thanks mine is a little more complex and I just simplified my code but perhaps I can still work it this way a bit. My problem is that I am hiding something in a $rootScope.broadcast and showing it again after. Making a 2 whole classes for show and hide seems a bit extreme. Updated to make it a little more obvious as to what I am dealing with.

Comment: I updated my example to use an event with the color passed in like your updated example.